# Error occurs when creating an overdue charge

Tags: acumatica

I use the framework to create an Overdue Charge.  In previous 5.20 version, there is no issue.  I upgraded the site to 6.0.  Now an error occurs:

> Error #115: An error occurred during processing of the field IsRUTROTDeductible : Index was outside the bounds of the array..

I create the ARInvoiceEntry graph.  Next the ARInvoice DAC, and populate the header fields.  Finally I call graph.Document.Insert(overduecharge).  Transactions are inserted later.

I do have some user fields in an extension table 'ARRegisterExtension'.  But that table uses the default InnerJoin, with the matching records from ARRegister included in the table

Please advise if an extra step must happen with RUTROTDeductible.  I'm not familiar with this entity.

Comment: Could you please also provide stack trace?

Comment: Could you please also provide exact number of 6.0 version?

Comment: Warning:  Index was outside the bounds of the array.  

   at _GetValueByOrdinal(ARInvoice , Int32 , PXCacheExtension[] )
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.GetValueByOrdinal(TNode data, Int32 ordinal, PXCacheExtension[] extensions)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode& A_0)

Comment: The build nbr is 6.00.1687
I noticed the field IsRUTROTDeductible is available in ARInvoice DAC, version 5.20.  It is removed in version 6.0

Comment: Yes, this field was moved to an extension. Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for **RUTROT** in your code. 
These fields were moved to an extension in 6.0, so these fields will not be available in **ARInvoice** DAC any more.
If you are setting these fields anywhere, please remove this code.
These fields are for Sweden users only, so, I don't think you need to set it.